# HP Fortify HttpWebRequest Error of Header Manipulation C#

Tags: c#, fortify

I am using `Fortify` to scan my code. It is identifying the error "Header Manipulation". My code is below.

```
HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(apiUrl);
httpRequest.Method = "POST";
httpRequest.ContentType = "application/xml; charset=UTF-8";

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dp_api_key))
    httpRequest.Headers.Add("apikey", dp_api_key);
httpRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", token);
```

Here the last line param "`token`" has issue reported by HP Fortify. 
I have found no way to make Fortify happy. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should probably file a bug or contact HP support. Or upgrade to a newer version of Fortify. There's nothing wrong with using headers in a REST call. It's not the first Fortify bug to appear here either

Comment: In your code example, you do not specify where `token` comes from.  If it is coming from an untrusted source (non-hard coded) then it could contain tainted data.  If you are not doing validation on it, then Fortify would have an issue with putting untrusted data into the header.  If you are validating it someone, Fortify might not have picked up on your way of doing validating and called it an error.  In that case it is a false positive and at which point you can submit it to Fortify.

Comment: thank you for your comments.